# withFilter Implementation while writing custom monad in scala

Tags: scala

I am not able to implement monad to compose function. It throws error in for comprehension that "value withFilter is not a member of MonadFunctionComposition.Writer"

```
object MonadFunctionComposition extends App {

  case class Writer(value1: Int, value2: Int, logs: String) {

    def map(x : (Int, Int) => Int): Writer = {
      Writer( x(value1, value2), x(value1, value2), logs)
    }

    def flatMap(x: (Int, Int) => Writer): Writer = {
      val temp = x(value1, value2)
      val temp1 = x(value2, value2)
      Writer(temp.value1, temp1.value2, logs + "..." + temp.logs)
    }
  }

  val f: (Int, Int) => Writer = (value1, value2) => {
    Writer(value1 + 57, value2 - 2, s"execute function f with $value1 $value2 value.")
  }

  val g: (Int, Int) => Writer = (value1, value2) => {
    Writer(value1 + 10, value2 - 1, s"execute function g with $value1 $value2 value.")
  }

  val result = for
  {
    (a,x) <- g(5, 100)
    b <- f(a,x)
  } yield b

 // val result = g(5, 100).flatMap((a,b) => f(a, b))
  println(s"Result $result")

}
```

Comment: using custom monads in `for comprehension` requires withFilter funciton implementation signature: `def withFilter(p: T => Boolean): Writer[T]` . Try to add function to your monad.

Comment: @BorisAzanov what should be the implementation of withFilter?

Comment: @abhi essential this is form of lazy `filter` - like you are applying filter, which will take action later during terminal operations. In case of for instance `List` - methods like toString, fold, etc.

Comment: @IvanKurchenko what should be the implementation of withFilter? I am not able to execute the code.

Comment: @IvanKurchenko It depends on you Monad implementation.  In general: if value inside monad does not satisfy predicate you should fallback into `error` or `empty` value. Btw, looking at your code - it's not really a monad, it is just a class which implements methods used by `for-comprehension`.

Comment: @IvanKurchenko Is not writer a Monad? If not could you please explain why? Also in the above code what should be the implementation of withFilter to run the code?

Answer (score 2):

Don't think that it's possible to have a useful `withFilter` implementation in this case.

Your `Writer` is not a monad. 
First, to be a monad it has to be generic (`Writer[T]`).

Second, `map` and `flatMap` must have proper signatures:

```
def map[B](f: T => B): Writer[B]
def flatMap[B](f: T => Writer[B]): Writer[B]
```

It's surprising that the compiler doesn't throw an error in your case.

And then you may think of adding `withFilter` method: 
`def withFilter(p: T => Boolean): Writer[T]`
But what should it do?

There is of course a trivial implementation that just does nothing and returns `this`.
Also it's possible to discard the log if `p(this)` is `false` but it's not what people expect.

Ability to do filtering on a monadic value is encoded in `MonadPlus` typeclass. And neither Scalaz/Cats nor Haskell implements `MonadPlus` for `Writer`.

Comment: Then how to compose function f and g using for comprehension in the above-mentioned case?

Comment: You may add to this answer that if you add the [**bm4** compiler plugin](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for) then that code would compile without needing to implement stupid `withFilter`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez seems I got the question wrong. I thought that OP actually wants to use `if` inside `for`

Comment: Pattern matching on values got from `<-` also uses `.withFilter` unless you use better-monadic-for.